Data querying tool in Deltalake
We are looking for a data querying tool in Deltalake to replace our current tool, SAP BO.

For our IT team, this new tool should allow us to:


Connect to Deltalake to retrieve data using direct query mode.
Build semantic data models or use an existing semantic model, such as Power BI's.
Customize the calendar for automatic extractions (e.g., Monthly B+2 (business day) will be 2 for August but 3 for September because September 1st is a weekend).
Create display folders and subfolders to organize tables and elements in the user interface. For example, we can have a folder called "Indicators" with subfolders like "AUM" and "Flows". In the "Flows" subfolder, we can have subfolders like "MTD," "QTD," and "YTD" containing specific indicators.


For end users, in the user interface, this tool will allow them to:


Build data queries by dynamically selecting, dragging, and dropping fields, as well as applying different filters.
Optionally create new fields (variables) by applying different conditions.
Extract data in Excel format.
Schedule Excel extractions to be saved in a local folder and sent via email.

Do you have any suggestion?
thank you
at the moment, we haven't found any tool that can meets our needs
